# Legal Info button greyed out in Eclipse installation details

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a feature plugin which includes a number of eclipse plugins, I created a p2 repository of the feature using maven build and installed the feature in eclipse, In eclipse when I click on Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details. Under the plugins tab I see the plugins that belong to the installed feature but when I click on any plugin the legal info button is not getting activated.

Do I need to provide some legal info in the plugin to enable the button once the plugin is selected? if yes where should I provide it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Legal Info button displays the contents of any `about.html` file in the plugin.

If you include an about.html don't forget to list in as part of the `build.properties` file so that it is included in the build.